# Oracle SQL for handling null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 3 columns: c1, c2 and c3.
I want to write a select statement so that if both c1 and c2 are null, display c3, otherwise display c1.

What would be the best way to write a select statement in the above scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)

```
CASE WHEN C1 IS NULL AND C2 IS NULL
     THEN C3
     ELSE C1
END
```

Using [NVL2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm)

```
NVL2(C1,C1,NVL2(C2,C1,C3))
```

OR

```
NVL2(C1||C2,C1,C3)
```

Using [DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)

```
DECODE(C1,NULL,DECODE(C2,NULL,C3,C1),C1)
```

Readability and ease wise CASE wins.

Comment: One of my colleagues had written like this. Is this a good way to handle this scenario?
select nvl2(c1||c2, c1, c3) from XXX

Comment: No it is wrong, if either c1 or c2 is null, c3 is returned in that expression, since concatenating any string with NULL gives NULL only, but we should always handle NULL before hand.As you dont know, which one was NULl, either c1 or c2.. also CASE would be everyone's choice.

Comment: I've tried my colleague's select statement in Oracle 11g and found that concating null string with another string literal will return the literal itself. 

So my colleague's solution works even though I also feel that "Case When" is a better solution.

Comment: Oracle is known to have a buggy NULL vs. '' (empty string) implementation. It treats both the same, usually but not always like NULL, e.g. **TRANSLATE('jhkhkxhkx', 'x', '')** will not work, you need **TRANSLATE('jhkhkxhkx', '.x', '.')** instead

Comment: It's not buggy, it's intended @dnoeth and the behaviour of TRANSLATE() is [well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145), so I don't see how you can call this buggy either.

Comment: @Ben: Just because it's documented it's still not a feature :-)  Why is '' treated differently when it's used in a concatenation? Why does ''/NULL as a paramter return ''/NULL in TRANSLATE, but not in REPLACE?  And of course any other RDBMS knows there's a difference between NULL and ''.

Comment: Because Oracle has determined it should be so and documented it as such. It is working as intended. Just because you disagree with how it should work does not make it a bug.